# Passing Variables from dataTable to Script

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have a visualforce page with a button to create a new record.  I was passing all of the default values to the standard new page using a link to pass the default values.  This visualforce page is not working in lighting, it does not pass the values to the standard page layout.

I have been working to fix this issue.  So far, in my datatable, I have the following to pass variables to my script.

```
<apex:dataTable width="100%" value="{!products}" var="product" rowClasses="odd, even">
                <apex:column headerValue="Product Name">                     
                    <apex:outputLink value="{!product.link}" rendered="{! $User.UIThemeDisplayed == 'Theme3' }">
                        {!product.p.Name}
                    </apex:outputLink>
                    <apex:outputLink onclick="newProd('{!product.p.Name}', '{!product.p.Category__c}')" rendered="{! $User.UIThemeDisplayed == 'Theme4d' }">
                        {!product.p.Name} 
                    </apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>
```

In the script, I am passing those values as default values... this is working.  However, I have several more fields that I need to pass.  I tried to just pass the product variable from the datatable but that just gives me an id.  Is there a way to pass the entire record from the datatable to the script?

```
<script> 
        function newProd(pName, prodCat) 
        { 
           var defaults = {'Opportunity__c' : '{!oppId}', 'Account__c' : '{!aId}', 'Name' : pname, 'Product_Category__c' : prodCat};
           sforce.one.createRecord('Opportunity_Products__c', '{!newRtId}', defaults);
        }
```

Adding that I am using a wrapper class to build the list.  When I console.log the product variable, I get the following:  "I should add that I am using a wrapper class to build the list. When I console log just product, I get the following:  "ExtProduct:[PlanDesignCategory=DA, link=/a0h/e?..... "
If I try to access product with product.ExtProduct it is undefined. How do I access the PlanDesignCategory variable?

Thank you!!!

Comment: what happens when you just output {!product.p} to the page in your column?

Comment: It passed the id for the record and not the entire object..

Comment: I updated the question with more info.. I'm using a wrapper class..